# Transaction block in Java?

Tags: java, transactions

What is the idiomatic way to perform a transaction in Java? I have some code

```
myObject oldVar = myVar.toMyObject();
myVar.mutationAndDBInsertion;
myObject newVar = myVar.toMyObject();
```

I want to wrap this all in a single transaction block, so that I am sure that the `myVar` object will not mutate unless the database operation is successful, and the `oldVar` and `newVar` will be accurate representations of the object state before and after the mutation. How should I approach this?

Comment: You could have `mutationAndDBInsertion` throw an exception if it fails. Then the next statement won't be reached. As for making sure any in-memory objects don't change states, there is nothing in Java itself to prevent that (or make it transactional).

Comment: As you are working with a database, implement transactions using database tools (SQL, for relational databases, for example). And if SQL transaction has committed successfully then process it in your java code. Otherwise the database engine will rollback the transaction and you don't need to write java code for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**Committing Transactions**

After the auto-commit mode is disabled, no SQL statements are committed until you call the method commit explicitly. All statements executed after the previous call to the method commit are included in the current transaction and committed together as a unit. The following method, CoffeesTable.updateCoffeeSales, in which con is an active connection, illustrates a transaction:

public void updateCoffeeSales(HashMap salesForWeek)
    throws SQLException {

```
PreparedStatement updateSales = null;
PreparedStatement updateTotal = null;

String updateString =
    "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
    "set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";

String updateStatement =
    "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
    "set TOTAL = TOTAL + ? " +
    "where COF_NAME = ?";

try {
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
    updateTotal = con.prepareStatement(updateStatement);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : salesForWeek.entrySet()) {
        updateSales.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
        updateSales.setString(2, e.getKey());
        updateSales.executeUpdate();
        updateTotal.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
        updateTotal.setString(2, e.getKey());
        updateTotal.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();
    }
} catch (SQLException e ) {
    JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    if (con != null) {
        try {
            System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
            con.rollback();
        } catch(SQLException excep) {
            JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(excep);
        }
    }
} finally {
    if (updateSales != null) {
        updateSales.close();
    }
    if (updateTotal != null) {
        updateTotal.close();
    }
    con.setAutoCommit(true);
}
```

}

**from ORACLE WEB Page**